# Event timestamps in a multi-threaded environment

Tags: java, time, timer

I'm working on some code for a web service and I want to keep track of how quickly requests are coming in. I'm doing this by recording a timestamp for each request, using `System.nanoTime()`. I chose that over `System.currentTimeMillis()` because I only care about time relative to the current time, not any calendar, and I don't want it to be affected by updates to the system clock.

However, it seems that `nanotime()` doesn't play nicely in a multi-core environment, as the startup time is going to be different for each CPU core.

I'm looking for a way to obtain a numerical (`long`) timestamp that is:

- Not related to the current calendar time
- Consistent across multiple cores/threads
- Relatively inexpensive (preferrably not using reflection)

Any ideas?

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` as well as `System.nanoTime()` are pulled from the underlying system.   
I read somewhere that `System.nanoTime()` does not always pull the processor time but on some implementations uses the battery timer. But I can't find the source anymore.   
Anyways, it uses the most precise timer available on the system (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime())

Comment: Do you compare results from **different** threads?

Comment: If you create any timestamp (System.currentTimeMillis()) when your program starts and then you create another, subtract those two, they'll be "amount of time elapsed", not related to calendar and anything else. They'll just be "how much time has passed since that moment and now".

Would it solve your problem?

Comment: Do you really want to post process thousands (millions) of numbers?  You might want to, instead, keep a count of requests over a time period (simple counter, then pull info over every (second? or other time period). Should be more accurate overall

Comment: `AtomicLong.incrementAndGet()` formally matches all your criteria.

Comment: @PM77-1 It's running on a web server, so it's entirely possible that requests will be handled by different threads.

@BrenoInojosa `System.currentTimeMillis()` will be affected by system clock synchronization updates, which happen periodically. This will result in strange behavior when that happens.

@Apangin `AtomicLong` has nothing to do with time.

Comment: What OS do you use? What problems with `System.nanoTime` do you experience? *"doesn't play nicely"* sounds vaguely.

Answer (score 0):

Unless threads are explicitly synchronised you cannot have guaranteed way to produce a clock values. Obviously it has performance impact. You should redesign your system not to rely on such clock. If you need a timings in multithreaded system, maybe you should look into [Vector Clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_clock).